# Can Esapi Java encoders be used encode xml text data?

Tags: regex, regex-negation, esapi

Can I use ESAPI java encoders to encode XML text data? Is there a separate encoder for XML text data? Will there be any discrepancies if I use ESAPI encoders to encode XML text data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ESAPI has an encoder for XML, see the doc [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.owasp.esapi/esapi/2.1.0/org/owasp/esapi/Encoder.java#Encoder.encodeForXML%28java.lang.String%29).

[image: Documentation]

However, if all you need is encoding/decoding, and you don't need all of the functionality provided by ESAPI, I would suggest you use [this](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Java_Encoder_Project) library instead, as currently ESAPI has lost OWASP flagship status and hasn't had active development for over a year now.

However, if you want to be able to detect multiple encoding attacks, there is no better alternative than using esapi and the `ESAPI.encoder().canonicalize()` method, or one of the dozens of other validation methods that can be used.

Comment: Update:  In 2016 I helped resurrect esapi, though we're still not quite to regular releases yet.